# c# Regex repeat group and split comma

Tags: c#, regex

I have a pattern like this `((1), (2), (3), ....)`

And I started to create a regex to match this pattern.

```
\(\(\d+\)\)
```

This patternt matches only `((2))` pattern but I want to continue with comma, and repeat the group pattern like this: `((1), (2), (3), ....)`

How can I do?

Comment: Are you trying to extract all digit sequences? Then use `Regex.Matches(s, @"[0-9]+")`. Or are you trying to validate and extract digit sequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex will match entire pattern:

```
\((?:\(\d+\))(?:,\s\(\d+\))*\)
```

**[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uNcZzy/2)**

Answer (score 0):

To match the whole input row use the following expression: `\((\(\d+\)|\,\s?)+\)`